# Are there any ways to get out of quicksand?

Tags: lethal-company

On the moon March with no hazardous condition, my friend seemed to have stepped in quicksand and died.  I had the unfortunate pleasure of watching him suffer with seemingly no way to help.

Is there anything you can do to get out of quicksand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to different sites (e.g. [The Nerd Stash](https://thenerdstash.com/how-to-deal-with-quicksand-in-lethal-company/), [PC Invasion](https://www.pcinvasion.com/how-to-deal-with-quicksand-in-lethal-company/), [Guide on Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=3061189785)) quicksand only appears when it's raining. It is possible to escape quicksand by immediately stepping back once you hear a bubbling noise indicating that you're caught in quicksand. You can also use the teleporter shortly after stepping in to escape. Once you're sunk to your waist you're considered to be submerged and cannot use the teleporter anymore.

Comment: It definitely wasn't raining. But it was a moon where the description says "constantly stormy" despite it not actually being stormy.